# Solder Mask Color Code

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly, solder-mask

Is there standard that recommend guidance of particular colors of solder mask?

A while back I was told by a local assembler that BLUE typically indicates the circuit is ROHS compliant. Yet my Google foo does not find any supporting evidence. Were my Google foo is swamped. So there may be something I just don't see.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence: "Were my Google foo is swamped."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The soldermask color is purely a function of designer preference, and whether the person paying for the boards is willing to foot the bill for custom soldermask colors. It has no relation to whether the board is ROHS compliant or anything else.

Green is the most common just because it's a defacto standard. You can get ROHS and non-ROHS green boards, as you can with any other coloring.

---

It's worth noting that it's entirely possible that **that assembler only** had an *in-house* standard where they ordered boards that needed to be ROHS compliant with a blue soldermask, and boards that *didn't* need to be ROHS with green (or any other color) soldermask. However, that would be a function of that assembler in particular, not an industry wide thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've used solder mask color to indicate version of the copper of a PCB. I use...Green = prototype, Red = REV A, Blue = REV B, White = REV C, Yellow = REV D, etc... This allows easy differentiation between copper revisions. It also allows production and repair technicians to know which PCB they are working with from across the room. More than once, a yellow PCB was in a tray of blue PCBs. This prevented an old revision from accidentally being installed in a new system

Comment: I suspect this would be better as a **comment** since it doesn't really answer the question (is there a **standard**?).

Comment: As a follow up, no